# How can I get larger fonts across the board in ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: css, extjs

I'm by no means an old man, but I find the font sizes overall in Ext JS (using 4.1) too small.

I'd like to change the overall default font size for EVERYTHING -- titles, buttons, grids, trees, form field labels, form fields, etc. and bump it up to about 120% of the default.

What are my best options here?

Creating a custom theme seems like extreme overkill (if that would work at all).

This is my solution now, which is in my main CSS file:

```
div, span, p, body, a, input, textarea, label {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial !important;
  font-size:    14px !important;
}
```

However, this feels hackish, and it this does evil things to my Grid column headers and tabs (their chrome doesn't stretch properly). It also makes it harder for situation where I *do* occasionally want a different font.

Comment: If you actually would go with @Jamie advise, can you please post a screenshots with result? I'm very interested in the same question you have.

Comment: I'm not trying to sell anything here but if you want an example of what it looks like when you bump up the font-size (and other things). Here's a theme we made at my company. http://www.newbridgegreen.com/view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the best way is to recompile the theme. That way all component will have their sizes recalculated based on your default font-size and you won't get a messed up look.

It's actually pretty easy to do. Follow the instructions here. [ExtJS Theme Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming).
Once you have made sure you can compile the default theme. Edit the file at **themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/variables/_core.scss** and on line 31, change the font-size to 14px.

Recompile.

Job done.

Comment: your theme actually looks very slick. I will contact you tomorrow from your company's website.

Comment: Cheers sha. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and it wasn't as painful as I feared... though Sencha really needs to clean up their SASS files, the numerous references to `ceil($font-size * .9)` made it more difficult than it should have been to change the font size across the board.

Comment: Yea it's a bit of a pain, nothing a sneaky find and replace doesn't fix though. Glad it worked out OK for you!